# Convert weekly Data frame to monthly data frame in R

Tags: r

My dat looks like below with different node_desc having weekly data for 4 years

```
         ID1     ID2   DATE_     value
1:     00001     436 2014-06-29 175.8164
2:     00001     436 2014-07-06 188.9264
3:     00001     436 2014-07-13 167.5376
4:     00001     436 2014-07-20 160.7907
5:     00001     436 2014-07-27 185.3018
6:     00001     436 2014-08-03 179.5748
```

would like to convert data frame to monthly.Trying below code

```
df %>%
  tq_transmute(select     = c(value,ID1),
               mutate_fun = apply.monthly,
               FUN        = mean)
```

But my output looks like below

```
DATE_                 value
  <dttm>                <dbl>
1 2014-06-29 00:00:00    144.
2 2014-07-27 00:00:00    143.
3 2014-08-31 00:00:00    143.
4 2014-09-28 00:00:00    152.
5 2014-10-26 00:00:00    156.
6 2014-11-30 00:00:00    166.
```

But I would like to have ID1,ID2,Date(monthly) and value(either getting the mean or max of 4 weeks) instead of just having date and value,because I have data of different ID1's for 4 years.Can someone help me in R

Comment: months are longer than 4 weeks. You need to define what to do with the overlaps and "underlaps". It's also ambiguous what you want as grouping.

Comment: I want the value(mean of month) with date(last day of month),ID1,ID2 columns in my output to perform some analysis on data set.

Comment: Your dataset doesn't support your request.

Answer (score 1):

Here's my take

```
dta <- data.frame(id1=rep("00001",6),id2=rep("436",6),
              date_=as.Date(c("29jun2014","6jul2014","13jul2014","20jul2014","27jul2014","3aug2014"),"%d%B%Y"),
              value=c(175.8164,188.9264,167.5376,160.7907,185.3018,179.5748))
```

And `dplyr` would do the rest. Here I summarize the data by taking the mean value

```
library(dplyr)
my_dta <- dta %>% mutate(month_=format(as.yearmon(date_),"%b"))
my_dta %>% group_by(.dots=c("id1","id2")) %>% summarise(mvalue=mean(value))
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem you have is that your dataset doesn't have daily data. The `apply.monthly` function comes from xts, but tidyquant uses wrappers around a lot of functions so they work in a more tidy way. `apply.monthly` needs an xts object, which is basicly a matrix with a time index.

Also know that apply.monthly returns the last available day of the month in your timeseries. Looking at your example set, the last day it returns for july 2017 will the 27th. Now if you have 5 records (weeks) in a month the mean function will do this over 5 records. It will never be exactly 1 month as weekly data never covers monthly data.

But with tidyquant you can get sort of a monthly result with ID1 and ID2 with your data if you join the outcome with the original data. See code below. I haven't removed any unwanted columns.

```
df1 %>%
  tq_transmute(select     = c(value, ID1),
               mutate_fun = apply.monthly,
               FUN        = mean) %>% 
  mutate(DATE_ = as.Date(DATE_)) %>% 
  inner_join(df1, by = "DATE_")

# A tibble: 3 x 5
  DATE_      value.x ID1   ID2   value.y
  <date>       <dbl> <fct> <fct>   <dbl>
1 2014-06-29    176. 00001 436      176.
2 2014-07-27    176. 00001 436      185.
3 2014-08-03    180. 00001 436      180.
```

data:

```
df1 <- data.frame(ID1 = rep("00001", 6),
           ID2 = rep("436", 6),
           DATE_ = as.Date(c("2014-06-29", "2014-07-06", "2014-07-13", "2014-07-20", "2014-07-27", "2014-08-03")),
           value = c(175.8164,188.9264,167.5376,160.7907,185.3018,179.5748)
           )
```